# UILongPressGestureRecognizer not working, but swapping it for a UITapGestureRecognizer works fine. Why?

Tags: ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIImageView` with a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` attached that never seems to detect a long press gesture no matter how I configure the gesture recognizer. However, if I swap it out for a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, ***that*** works just fine. What could possibly be going on?

This is how I'm configuring my `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`:

```
UIImageView* cellView = (UIImageView*)[view viewWithTag:5];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPressGestureRec =
    [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellLongPress:)];
longPressGestureRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
longPressGestureRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
longPressGestureRec.minimumPressDuration = 0.4;
[cellView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRec];
[longPressGestureRec release];
```

This is what `cellLongPress` looks like:

```
-(void)cellLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    // This never gets called.
    NSLog(@"someone long pressed me");
}
```

Pretty straightforward, right? No luck so far getting it to work, though. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a problem doing the 'alloc' for every UIImageView of the UITableView?  I see that cellView uses viewwithTag to a pre-allocated instance.  Does each UILongPressGestureRecognizer also need to be pre-allocated for each cell of the UITableView?

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem. The problem was answered nearly 3 years ago... see the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `numberOfTapsRequired` is set to `1` which means the user has to tap once *before* starting the long press (finger down, finger up, finger down for 0.4 seconds, gesture recognized).

Change `numberOfTapsRequired` to `0` (which is the default).

For that property, the documentation just says:

> The number of taps on the view required for the gesture to be
>   recognized.

But in the comments in `UILongPressGestureRecognizer.h`, it says:

> The number of full taps required before the press for gesture to be
>   recognized

Comment: Actually it defaults to 1, so your answer still stands and is of even greater importance than you thought.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITapGestureRecognizer/numberOfTouchesRequired

Comment: Joe is correct that for taps the default is 1 (although he meant the link below).

However, Anna's answer is nonetheless insightful. There is a subtle difference between tap = 1 and tap = 0. A tap is more of a forceful gesture. With tap = 0 and touches = 1 you can rest your finger down on the screen to trigger a long press (something people might come to this page for) Taps = 1 requires a more intentional touch.

Updated Link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITapGestureRecognizer/numberOfTapsRequired