# UILongPressGestureRecognizer didn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I added 4 gesture recoginzer to a UIImageView , the single tap , double tap and pin gestures work fine . However, long press gesture didn't work . Why is that?

```
        _imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES ;

    //single tap
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc ]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapAction:) ]  ;
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1 ;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1 ;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapAction:)] ;
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1 ;
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2 ;
    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap] ;

    //pin gesture
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer  *pin = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinch:)] ;

    //long press gesture
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressAction:) ] ;
    [longPress requireGestureRecognizerToFail:singleTap ] ;
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1 ;
    longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1 ;
    longPress.numberOfTapsRequired = 1 ;

    [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:longPress] ;
    [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:pin] ;
    [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap] ;
    [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap] ;


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```

Hey guys, I add the `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` method and set the long press gesutre delegate , but that still did not work .

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628874/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-not-working-but-swapping-it-for-a-uitapgesturereco?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error maybe here

```
[longPress requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longPress ] ;
```

Why longPress require failed to itself ? delete it.

You don't understand requireGestureRecognizerToFail command. It use when a gesture need other failed to fired. If longPress don't fired, then tapGesture fired. 
  In your case pinch failed -> longPress failed -> double tap failed -> single tap
Also delete this line: longPress.numberOfTapsRequired = 1 ;

Comment out your code and use this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.imageView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    UIGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1 ;
    longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1 ;
    [longPress requireGestureRecognizerToFail:pinchGesture];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [doubleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longPress];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}

- (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    NSLog(@"Pinch");
}


- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    NSLog(@"LongPress");
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    NSLog(@"Double Tap");
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    NSLog(@"Single Tap");
}
```

Comment: Sorry,my original code is `[longPress requireGestureRecognizerToFail:singleTap ] ;` , and I delete this line    
of code , the long press still can't work .

Comment: That's wrong!use [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longPress];

Answer (score 0):

Try using this delegate method :-

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
 }
```

You also missed this:- `longPress.delegate = self;`

Comment: Add this :- longPress.delegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

In order for the long press gesture recognizer to work, the single tap gesture recognizer has to fail first.

In your code, you specify that the long press gesture recognizer itself is the one that has to fail (which is wrong). You should change:

```
[longPress requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longPress ] ;
```

to:

```
[longPress requireGestureRecognizerToFail:singleTap ] ;
```